# I have a SQL db file, I want to use it in Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Is there any way possible, to upload a SQL DB file stored locally on disk to Azure SQL Server? Its already populated with data and I'd like to use it for learning the Azure environment and creating web apps alongside it. NOTE: this is not a SQL Server DB file, its just a regular standalone db file with data populated into it.

Comment: Is this file a backup file or something else? We need to know what kind of file it is before we can suggest a migration approach. By Azure, do you mean SQL inside a VM (IaaS) or SQL Azure (Paas)?

Comment: Its not a backup, its just a regular SQL db file that contains tables with data, nothing else. I could convert it to SQLite and edit the data as well, and export it back into a .db file.

Comment: Are you saying it’s a file full of table creation and insert statements?

Comment: Precisely. I can even pull up the file on visual studio and see all the insert statements.

Comment: Then I guess you just need to connect to a database in SQL Server Management Studio and run it. First you need to create the database. Before that you need to decide what platform. SQL Azure is the simplest.

Answer (score -2):

There's a tool called Data Migration Assistant, you can download here. It's quite intuitive to use. 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595